# change screen angle .NET

Tags: .net, windows, screen

Does anyone know how can I change screen angle from .NET Framework 4? (you can not use  Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms in this version of .NET I believe).

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I want to rotate screen on .NET 4

Comment: That's a feature of portable devices.  .NET 4 only supports heavy ones.  If you try to target a Windows Mobile device then you need .NET CF and steer clear from .NET 4.  Future slates with Metro require .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0):

.NET has no built-in functions to do this.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1948-change-display-settings-programmatically.aspx) it describes how to use PInvoke to manipulate the display.